# I cannot catch exceptions in method annotated @Transactional

Tags: spring, transactions, rollback

I cannot catch exceptions in method annotated `@Transactional`. 
I want to send mail to created user if `save` operation succeded.

When username is already in use PostgreSQL throws exception `PSQLException` which is extention of `SQLExcpetion` which is extention of `Exception`. I couldn't catch `Exception` and `PSQLException` then I tried to catch `Throwable` and this is working, but not resolve my problem and come to that catching `Throwable` is the cause of new problem.

1. When I get DataIntegrityViolationException (this is an excpetion from Spring) I want to propagate its because I have handler for my controller which returns statement and status specified for this concrete exception. And when I catch Throwable I have to throw always RuntimeException.
2. Very strange thing is that `emailSender.sendEmail()` is called even if some exception was thrown. But if `userRepository` is throwing an exception any method should not be called and exception should be caught in `catch` statement and then transaction should be rollback. Do I correct understand transactions or not?

Implementation of my service:

```
@Transactional
public UserEntity createUser(UserEntity user) {
    try {
        final UserEntity saved = userRepository.save(user);
        emailSender.sendEmail(saved);
        return saved;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Come to that when I try debug this method using IDEA, debugger doesn't enter catch statement, but my handlers annotated `@RestControllerAdvice` are catching this exception.

Any idea what's wrong or maybe do you know similar questions?

Comment: Spring's `@Transactional` wraps the exceptions thrown from the actual method into its own hierarchy of exceptions. That's the reason you are not able to catch `SQLException` or any other exception which is actually thrown. Please take a look at the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: Any way to execute the catch block with @Transactional annotation ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experienced the same issue. Fixed using `saveAndFlush`.

This make sense because with transactional, transaction is being committed(to db) after executing the function. But with `saveAndFlush`, it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is enclosed within transactional, Even with saveAndFlush also, the transaction is being committed(to db) after executing the function